# Update settings - ignoring some updates?

Tags: updates

Using Ubuntu 15.10 - Wiley - updates check once per week, which is fine, however I see no option to NOT update certain items, IE codecs for browsers I do not use. Instead the update will bug me every day to install it, there is no option to ignore a specific update?

Comment: I believe Ubuntu tries to update every package that is installed.  From my own limited knowledge set I would suggest one of two options.  You can ['pin'](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package) a package to a certain release, which may cause problems later, or you can uninstall packages that you will never use.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to prevent the update notification for particular packages easily, but it's possible to define different notification intervals for security and other updates in `software-properties-gtk`:

[image: software-properties "updates" screenshot]

Since (browser) codec updates are often non-critical, you should be able to delay the notification about them, so that they're less of a nuisance.

Comment: I did try that, but now I am getting even more. I will have to keep playing with these settings even if I have to turn everything off.  I am showing the same settings in your pic, except for "unsupported updates" which is checked, but still getting daily notifications of browser extensions, (check for updates is set to weekly). Rather odd, but I am a rather new user from win XP, so not really familiar with this yet. I remember that for win updates you could deny certain updates and they never would reappear. Guess that doesnt happen here.

Comment: Wait… browser extension? These aren't typically managed by Apt. Which browser and how did you install them?

Comment: It wants to install additional codecs for chrome, I do not have chrome, nor do I need additional codecs. I do have Pale Moon installed and it is the only browser I use.

Comment: What is "it" and what is the exact name of what "it" wants to install?

Comment: It is the "software updater" in Wily -

Comment: evry day it wants me to intall - security updates for firefox web browser, english language pack for FF, extra ffmpeg codecs for chrome, etc. I have none of these, so i do not want the updates, I only have important security updates for Ubuntu  checked, nothing else. In windows you can check "ignore" updates and it will exclude them from ever trying to update. In this, they just keep showing up. There is no way to turn them off without turning off all updates?

Comment: If these packages weren't installed on you computer, then they wouldn't need to be updated. Frequent security updates are enabled for a good reason. If you don't use these applications and are annoyed buy their update notifications, uninstall their respective packages. Note that this will also uninstall the `ubuntu-desktop` meta-package, which depends on `firefox`.